# ReadProcessMemory returns the same data for any address

Tags: windows, winapi

Working on WinXP SP3.
Visual Studio 2005.

Trying to read memory of another process.

```
    std::cout<<"Reading Process Memory\n";

 const DWORD pid = 3476;
HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,pid);
if(handle == NULL) {std::cout<<"Failed to open process\n";return 0;}

char* buffer1 = new char[256];
char* buffer2 = new char[256];
memset(buffer1,0,256*sizeof(char));
memset(buffer2,0,256*sizeof(char));
DWORD nbr = 0;
int address = 0x400000; 
BOOL result = ReadProcessMemory(handle,&address,buffer1,32,&nbr);
if(result!=1) std::cout<<"Failed to read memory\n";
address = 0x400000+0x1000;
result = ReadProcessMemory(handle,&address,buffer2,32,&nbr);
if(result!=1) std::cout<<"Failed to read memory\n";

int i = 0;
while(i++<10)
{
    if(buffer1[i]!=buffer2[i]) {std::cout<<"Buffers are different\n";break;}
}

delete[] buffer1;
delete[] buffer2;
CloseHandle(handle);
std::cin>>i;
return 0;
```

The problem is that both buffers are getting the same values. ReadProcMemory returns 1 and number of bytes read is the same as requested.

Comment: What exactly is in the buffers? They could be all zeroes, for example. BTW, it's never necessary to multiply by `sizeof(char)` since the size of char is defined to always be 1. Basically, `sizeof` gives the numbers of chars in the given object.

Comment: As you read memory at the address `&address` twice what else do you expect? It reads memory at some address that's equal to the address of local variable on current thread's stack.

Comment: The buffer has: FE FF FF FF 34 FF 12 and so on. Seems like functions reads something but what?

Comment: qwm i'm reading the address 0x400000 then 0x400000+0x1000 (at a different address). The function requires pointer to variable which holds the address to read.

Comment: @zulunation No, it's not. What gain would there be of adding another level of indirection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calls to ReadProcessMemory are incorrect.  You should be using `address` directly, not `&address`.  You may need to cast it to a `const void *`.

```
result = ReadProcessMemory(handle, reinterpret_cast<const void *>(address), buffer, 32, &nbr);
```

And you probably should declaring `address` as a type large enough to handle a pointer, like `std::ssize_t` or `INT_PTR`.

```
INT_PTR address = 0x400000;
```

Comment: This is my mistake. The MSDN states: A pointer to the base address in the specified process from which to read. I understood that a base address in the specified process here meaning a variable.

Answer (score 0):

buffer couldn't be a char, it has to be int, thats a working example

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
int point1=0; 
int i=0;
int d=0;
char* value[4]; 
SIZE_T stBytes = 0; 

HWND hwnd; 
HANDLE phandle; 
DWORD pid; 

hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "calc"); // calc is the name of the windows     process 
if (hwnd != 0) { 
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid); 
    phandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid); 
} else { 
    cout << "process is not executing"; 
    cin.get(); 
    return 0; 
} 

if (phandle != 0) { 
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) // 4 or wathever
{

    cout << "The pointer is 0x1001000" << endl; //Print the pointer 
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)0x1001000+i, &point1, 4,    &stBytes); //Get the content from 0x1001000 and store it in point1 
    cout << "decimal content point1 " << point1 << " (DEC)" << endl;   //Print the decimal content of point1
    printf("%x \n",point1); // print hexadecimal content of point1
    char *p=(char*)&point1; // point point1 buffer
    for(d=0;d<4;d++)
    printf("%x",(unsigned int)(unsigned char) *(p+d)); // print backwards    (because the buffer is like a LIFO) and see the dbg debugger  
}
    ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)point1, &value, 6, &stBytes);    //Get the value that is in the address pointed by the pointer 
    cout << "The value in the non-static address is " << (char*)value <<   endl << endl; //Print the value 

    cout << "Press ENTER to exit." << endl; 
    cin.get(); 
 } else { 
    cout << "Couldn't get a handle"; 
    cin.get();
     // address 0x1001000 content hex 5278DA77       


} 
}
```